# JPA Repository.save with Unique Key constraints

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using JPA to make an insert into my POSTGRES db. I recently added a Unique key constraint on one of the tables. The table looks like this:

```
______________________________________________
|Id|  Action|  Actor|  Assignee|  Date|  Team|
----------------------------------------------
```

Id is the primary Key and the combination of Action, Actor, Assignee and Date is an unique key. When I get the JSON object from the 3rd party API i use the following method to save the data into the database.

```
streamItemArray.parallelStream().forEach(streamItem -> {
                try{
                    streamItemRepository.save(streamItem);
                }catch(ConstraintViolationException e){
                    System.out.println("Issue with unique key");
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println("others");
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

the code ran for the first few time and now it is not running at all.

```
2017-07-31 15:14:04.811  WARN 7867 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
2017-07-31 15:14:04.812 ERROR 7867 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "Unique_key"
  Detail: Key (action, actor, assignee, date)=(Dismissed, Karen William, Karen William, 2017-07-21 01:19:05 IST) already exists.
2017-07-31 15:14:04.812  INFO 7867 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
others
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [Unique_key]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

My question here is:

1. How do we handle duplicates when we insert into db using JPA?
2. When using the foreach statement, if one repository.save fails will it execute the next item in foreach or does it stop the complete execution there itself?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Use Set instead of a List to filter out the duplicates.

Comment: Have you added uniqueConstraints in your enity?

Comment: yes I have added unique constraints - `@Table(name = "workflow", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"action", "actor", "assignee", "date"})})`

Comment: @AbdullahKhan - Could you elaborate on your comment. I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Map your incoming json to an object class say X. Override equals and hashcode properly based on object equality according to your business logic in class X. Perform the same logic you are performing above.

Comment: I think it would help a lot to see the structure of the entity.